# Can a comment be added to the end of the configuration line in pg_hba.conf file?

Tags: postgresql, syntax, comments

All examples I have seen have a comment on a separate line.

Is the following trailing comment OK?

```
host    all   all    0.0.0.0/0   md5     # accept all connections
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add a comment like that. To quote [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) (I added bolding for emphasis):

> Blank lines are ignored, as is **any text after the # comment character**.